# code coverage of inline function

Tags: c++, inline, code-coverage

I have observed, in some of the my header file some of the functions are covered but some functions are not getting hit even if the function is called.

I have used the following options while compiling.

`-fno-elide-constructors -O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fno-inline  -fno-inline-small-functions  -fno-default-inline`

I am not able to figure out why it is happening.

I am using gcc compiler and gcov.

example:

hpp

```
Class myclass
{

Myclass();

Getvalue();

};

0 Inline myclass::myclass()

0 {

0   .....

0 }

12 Inline myclass::getvalue()

12    {

12    .....

12   }
```

.cpp

```
12 Myclass abj1;

12 Obj1.getvalue();
```

I am using the following Gcov version v1.10, gcc version v4.4.5 and using it on Linux/EE50.

Comment: Can you give an example with some code?

Comment: Also, give us the version of the compiler and gcov as well as the system you are using. I've noticed that some combinations are broken in exactly the way you describe, while others work. Example: Ubuntu 12.04 + GCC 4.6 -> OK, Ubuntu 12.04 + GCC 4.7 -> Problem.

Comment: Note that `inline` function must be defined in every file in which it is used.

Comment: @SAM No. An inline function *may* be defined in multiple *compilation units* (non inline-functions must be defined in exactly one) but it does not have to be defined in a compilation unit where it is used, so long as it is *declared* in that compilation unit and *defined* in another compilation unit.

Comment: @cdhowie: No. "An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used." (C++11 3.2/2)

Comment: @MikeSeymour Odd. To my knowledge, and based on everything I've read, `inline` only informs the linker that it is not an error for the symbol to be defined in multiple compilation units.  It seems this conventional wisdom is not correct.

Comment: I read that line in TC++PL 3rd ed. (by the lord) Section 9.2

Comment: @DanielFrey:- I am using the following Gcov version v1.10
gcc version v4.4.5 and  using it on Linux/EE50

Comment: @MikeSeymour odr-used ? what is odr?

Comment: @SAM: "ODR" means "one definition rule"; loosely speaking "odr-used" means "used in a way which requires a definition". So a function is odr-used if you call it or take its address.

Comment: @mayank: gcov version seems fine to me, but is upgrading GCC an option for you? 4.4 sounds a bit too old to me for coverage tests. We use it (4.4) as a baseline in the company and it's used for the production build, but to run coverage tests we have to use 4.6 to get good results.

Comment: @DanielFrey: Thanks for replying. i am confused why some inline functions being covered and others not. upgrading GCC is not an option as we use 4.4 for production build. is there any other way some switch while compiling or some version of GCOV which is good with GCC4.4. why 4.6 gives good coverage number.

Comment: @mayank: There is no switch, I *believe* these are bugs in GCC which were only fixed in later version, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but it is something I am trying to work around in our build system.

We only instrument the library-under-test for code coverage; not the unit test program.  This is deliberate as we don't want unit test coverage to skew the metrics - there can be a lot of test code and it will all be invoked!

However this means that definitions in headers which are only invoked from the unit tests directly will appear not to be covered - because they are part of the unit test program binary and not from the library-under-test.

This applies to inline code and templates.

For templates, we can explicitly instantiate selected realizations in the library-under-test code, `extern`ed in the header.  This may be desirable if they are expected to be common use cases.  This also ensures that the template entities can be compiled.

For non-template inline code, ensuring it is *used* within the library should get that usage recorded as code-coverage, but still not direct usage in a test case.

I would caveat all this with the reminder that code coverage from unit tests is not an assertion that the unit tests are complete - it should only be taken as a confidence factor.  However I'd insist that every header file is represented to prove that they have been part of a translation unit.